# Calling fgets() twice causes second call to not complete

Tags: c, fgets

I have been Googling this problem for hours and so far I haven't seen any mention of it.

```c
int getInt()
{
    char* rawin = (char*)malloc(100);
    printf("How big should the secret code be?\n(Input number of elements):\n");

    while(fgets(rawin, 100, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        if (sscanf(rawin,"%d") == 1)
        {
          break;
        }
        printf("Numbers only please.\n");
    }
    int in = atoi(rawin);
    free(rawin);
    return in;
}
```

If I call this function twice, whichever one I call first works fine, but the second behaves strangely. Rather than entering the while loop, the program behaves as if looping indefinitely over fgets. The second call of fgets never completes, so never returns anything. When debugging, breakpoints placed anywhere after "while(fgets...", including after the loop, are never reached. I have tried appending "\n", "\0" and "\n\0" to the end of stdin, which did nothing. I have tried 'flushing' stdin by reading out every character that isn't '\n' or \0', which also did nothing.

Edit: To clarify, the condition in the 'if' statement is a placeholder.

Comment: What does `for` stands for ?

Comment: Are you sure that there is enough input to be read by the second round of the loop? `fgets` will block if the buffer on `stdin` is empty. Where is that input is coming from? If your first iteration never had your break condition then the first while loop will have read until `EOF` and the second will block indefinitely unless whatever sends the input decided to revive the pipe and send more data.

Comment: @HalimQarroum: That was supposed to be a placeholder. Will fix.

Comment: `fgets` returns a pointer, not an integer. Test against NULL.

Comment: I am not sure, but does putting a `getchar()` after the 1st loop help?

Comment: Can you provide a small working example with two function calls that replicates it?

Comment: @SuvP: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @teppic: Done. Same thing happens if I call this function twice.

Comment: You can't just not pass a parameter to `sscanf()` with your current format string... that's going to cause it to write somewhere random and who knows what will happen. If you want `sscanf()` to eat the number, use `%*d` instead. Hard to say if it's causing *this* problem, but it certainly is a problem.

Comment: @FatalError: It was causing this problem, fixed by adding the missing parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the data someplace:

```
if (sscanf(rawin,"%d") == 1)
```

That is, your `sscanf()` needs a third argument: a pointer to an integer where you want to store the result of this conversion:

```
int in;
if (sscanf(rawin,"%d",&in) == 1)
```

You don't need to call `atoi()` after this.

---

As a side note, there's no need for dynamically allocated memory in your example. A simple array would suffice:

```
char rawin[100];
```

Comment: @CybeatB Glad I could help. Next time include **all** of your code, or at least the smallest amount that reproduces the error. It wasn't clear what was going on until you removed the obfuscations from your earlier post.

Answer (score -3):

Try making stdin non-blocking.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

fcntl(0, F_SETFL, fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);
```

Or alternatively use a non-blocking `recv` instead of fgets:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

while(recv(0, inputString, 100, MSG_DONTWAIT) > 0)
```